# Vuejs return data from marker.on to data

Tags: google-maps, vuejs2

I want to store data to the v-model when you pick up the marker and drop it.
The console.log works fine but this.latitude doesn't and also the hidden field is not filled.

How can i achieve this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="lat" v-model="lat">

export default{
    data: function () {
        return {
            lat: '51.8778909'
    },
    addMarker: function (lat, lng) {
            var latlng = new L.LatLng(lat, lng)
            marker = new L.marker(latlng, {draggable: 'true'})
            map.setZoom(19)

            map.panTo(latlng)
            marker.on('dragend', function (event ) {

                this.latitude = lat
                console.log(lat);
                .......
}
```

Comment: Where is `latitude` defined in your Vue? Also, inside your callback (`marker.on`), `this` will not be the Vue. You need to properly capture `this`.

Comment: @BertEvans What do you mean?

Comment: In your code you set `this.latitude = lat` in your callback. But there is no `latitude` property defined in your data.

Comment: @BertEvans Ah so, correct, is an example ;) Do you have a typescript solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lat" v-model="lat" id="lat">

document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.lat;
```

This way the value of the hidden field is filled and can be post for save.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). If your app isn't updating it is probably because of reactivity

Comment: How can i achieve this into my example?

Comment: If you add a property to your model it will not be updated inlees you tel vuejs to updat it.  Because it is already bindend. Take a look at the examples on the page.. hoe you do that with typescript i don't know

Comment: i solved it with document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.lat;